# Scoped aggregates and WHERE scope

Tags: google-bigquery

The following query runs and produces 16 rows of output (as verified by wrapping in a `SELECT count(*) FROM (query)`) hits is a repeated record. hits.customDimensions is repeated inside hits. customDimensions is repeated in the main record.

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  hits.type,
  FIRST(IF(customDimensions.index = 10, customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS gacid,
  FIRST(IF(hits.customDimensions.index = 11, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN hits AS blogCategories
FROM
  [dataset.ga_sessions_20160902]
WHERE
  fullVisitorId ='55555555555'
```

however

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  hits.type,
  FIRST(IF(customDimensions.index = 10, customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS gacid,
  FIRST(IF(hits.customDimensions.index = 11, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN hits AS blogCategories
FROM
  [dataset.ga_sessions_20160902]
WHERE
  fullVisitorId ='55555555555'
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
```

fails with

```
Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields customDimensions.index and hits.type.
```

Is only a single (unflattened) record being returned and my wrapped count not giving me real results? Why can the two scoped aggregate work on different scopes, but a `WHERE` on the inner most scope fails?

Answer (score 1):

to avoid producing cross product try below

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  hits.type,
  FIRST(IF(customDimensions.index = 10, customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS gacid,
  FIRST(IF(hits.customDimensions.index = 11, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN hits AS blogCategories
FROM [dataset.ga_sessions_20160902]
WHERE fullVisitorId ='55555555555'
HAVING hits.type = 'PAGE'
```

Btw, in Legacy SQL any outermost SELECT produces flattened result (unless you write resuly into table with respective options - large result and unflattened ) - which explains the issue in your example

Comment: "which explains the issue in your example" No, it doesn't. That is why I said I tested the size by placing it inside a "select count(*) from ()" query. Also, there is no cross product being performed, the engine has the context it needs to avoid that.

Comment: i hear you :o( Does the workaround work for you? Or you are just interested in getting issue explained? Which most likely will come from GBQ Team

Comment: Another alternative is an explicit FLATTEN. I was more interested in why this was happening. I made a bug report as elsewhere I was told I should https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=694&thanks=694&ts=1473356481

Comment: I think your solution is not equivalent to the original query. By filtering hits after SELECT, it will cause extra hits to be considered in the scoped aggregation.

Comment: agree. it can be a case  - depends on actual data - i don't have relevant data to test. so proposed it on fly for "just to try"